# how to insert input text at selectbox(dropdown)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, bootstrap-4

I want to make a input text at selectbox in Jquery.

If the value in input box, result is input type text value.
If the value in selectbox option, results are options.

Selectbox value is multiple value.

Here's code.

```
<div class="form-group label-floating">       
    <label class="control-label">Terminal</label>                     
    <select id="selTerminalCode" class="selectpicker" data-style="select-with-transition" title="" data-size="10" multiple>
        <option>option1</option>
        <option>option2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1Tjx.png)

Comment: Not clear. Do you want the input field value inserted in the select or the select value in the input box?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you...

```css
 .select-editable {
     position:relative;
     background-color:white;
     border:solid grey 1px;
     width:120px;
     height:18px;
 }
 .select-editable select {
     position:absolute;
     top:0px;
     left:0px;
     font-size:14px;
     border:none;
     width:120px;
     margin:0;
 }
 .select-editable input {
     position:absolute;
     top:0px;
     left:0px;
     width:100px;
     padding:1px;
     font-size:12px;
     border:none;
 }
 .select-editable select:focus, .select-editable input:focus {
     outline:none;
 }
```

```html
<h3> Editable Dropdown </h3>
<div class="select-editable">
    <select onchange="this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="115x175 mm">115x175 mm</option>
        <option value="120x160 mm">120x160 mm</option>
        <option value="120x287 mm">120x287 mm</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="format" value="" />
</div>

<br/>
<h3> Using HTML5 </h3>
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Happy Coding :-)